# PHP, MySql Filling select box after press add button and send data to database

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

i have two select box i can add my choice from first box to 2nd box 2nd remove 2nd box to 1st box.
i can add all option from 1st box but not remove all from 2nd(at least one option there).

now how can i send this data in database. please give me solution.

Comment: show us what have you tried, with some code!

Comment: You need to be a little more specific...

Comment: add values of all the list items or options in the second list box to a hidden text box seperated by ',' or something and in the php get the values seperated by ',' and store it in database.